# org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication with spring-core 3.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-3, hibernate3

I am going to create simple rest service using `spring 3` and `hibernate 3`. There is no chance for me to use higher version of spring due to legacy business component that is based on hibernate 3.

For such purposes I've tried to use `SpringApplication.run`, bet recieved following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames
```

Is it possible to use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with old spring version? Would be good to know any alternative ways in this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot (and all the related tools, e.g the maven plugin) expect Spring v4 and above. Please see the official documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements).

By default, Spring Boot 1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT requires Java 7 and Spring Framework 4.1.5 or above.

Comment: Thanks javapapo for quick answer! Do you know any alternative approaches to avoid spring boot?

Comment: Well it really depends on what you want to do. Either you migrate to Spring Boot / Spring 4 combo (whatever that means to your code base), or you try to leverage the existing Spring modules on the versions you are (3) and develop your solution. I guess using Spring MVC (Spring REST) would be a potential solution see [here](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/)